# ASP .Net MVC 5 redirect issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently I have an internal server `serv` that has an application `app`.

It is running MVC 5 and has 2 pages `Account`/`Logon` which maps to controller and an action.

And  `Orders/Display` (again controller/action)

In order for internet users in the outside world to see I have a host server `host` running IIS.  It maps host URLs to the internal app like so

host`/Account/Logon` -->`serv/app/Account/Logon`

So basically anything after `host/...` gets changed to `serv/app/....`

My problem is if I do `RedirectToAction("Display","Orders");`
(there are lots of these redirects because there's lots of controller/action combos.

The internal server grabs the host portion but also tacks on "app" in order
to switch to the next page or route

So,`host/app/Orders/Display`
My problem is that the host IIS maps this URL to `host/app/app/Orders/Display`
because that what it's mapping is set to do.  always add "app"

How can I solve this issue?  Is there any way for `serv` do
a relative mapping?   In order words it only sees the original  `host/Account/Logon`
so on switch it would be `host/Orders/Display`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Redirect()` instead of `RedirectToAction()` and pass in the url.

Comment: I was hoping for an ASP ServerVariable that I could change
so that AppDomainAppVirtualPath does not get put into path

Comment: Html.BeginForm   also had the same problem.  In that case I probably had  to code HTML directly with custom URL path.

What we eventually did is create a new website put the application under that with port 81 binding and change the mapping to go port 81 and the top of IIS.  That way "app" would only show once in the path.